# Alert view from tabbar

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller, uialertview, tabbar, uitabbaritem

Like this video link [enter link description here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zDWSaItF2ko),I search around,got some idea by this [enter link description here](https://github.com/pkesaj/TabbarItemAlert),but this project always open a alert with a background of selectedindex=0 , I need a background as last viewcontroller as in video.How can I get a index of previous tabbar from tabbarcontroller.

Answer (score 0):

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool
    {
        print("your previous index is",tabBarController.selectedIndex)
        return true
    }
```

Comment: I tried this with your code and it is working @Shangari C